# How i get backspace (Delete) click key event in AccessibilityService class?

Tags: java, android, accessibility, accessibilityservice, android-studio-4.0

I want to get android keyboard backspace click event in the accessibility service class,
I tried many solutions for but not working all, if anyone has a experience to do work in accessibility service then suggest me solution.

```
public class AccessService extends AccessibilityService implements OnPrimaryClipChangedListener, OnLoadCompleteListener<Cursor>, Callback {
   
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
        switch (accessibilityEvent.getEventType()) {
          case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED:
          break;
      }
    }
}
```

**I want to detect keypress in this class**

Thanks in advance.